# CSS make text area blink

Tags: css

I got some price tables and added a "div overlay" to make the 3 price tables clickable, but that is messing up everything. It adds a horizontal frame above the tables (see link) and the price tables start to blink really fast when you move your mouse over the horizontal frame (the frame/box should not be above the price tables in the first place).

The grey hover color is of cause just a debug thingy ;)

Any suggestions what can be causing this?

Url: http://www.loveftp.com

Comment: there is some collision zone in you links, i think you have to place every link one by one and not by one css style for all or a group

Answer (score 0):

Try making the three divs `position:absolute`. They fight with each other for percentage width.